# How to recover a oracle backup file

Tags: database, oracle

I got a backup file ( Oracle 10g) file from one of my friend . When backup was created these are the messages :-

```
Warning: Log archiving (ARCHIVELOG mode) is currently disabled. If
you restore the database from this backup, any transactions that take
place between this backup and the next backup will be lost. It is
recommended that you enable ARCHIVELOG mode before proceeding so
that all transactions can be recovered upon restore. See the section
'Enabling ARCHIVELOG Mode...' in the online help for instructions.
Backup with log archiving disabled will shut down and restart the
database. Are you sure [Y/N]? y
Backup in progress...

Recovery Manager: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jul 26 17:54:02 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: XE (DBID=2585947637)

RMAN> set echo on;
2> shutdown immediate;
3> startup mount;
4> configure controlfile autobackup format for device type disk clear;
5> configure retention policy to redundancy 2;
6> configure controlfile autobackup on;
7> sql "create pfile=''C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\SERVER\DATABASE\SPF
ILE2INIT.ORA'' from spfile";
8> backup as backupset device type disk database;
9> configure controlfile autobackup off;
10> alter database open;
11> delete noprompt obsolete;
12>
echo set on

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
database closed
database dismounted
Oracle instance shut down

connected to target database (not started)
Oracle instance started
database mounted

Total System Global Area     251658240 bytes

Fixed Size                     1286820 bytes
Variable Size                 92278108 bytes
Database Buffers             155189248 bytes
Redo Buffers                   2904064 bytes

RMAN configuration parameters are successfully reset to default value

old RMAN configuration parameters:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 2;
new RMAN configuration parameters:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 2;
new RMAN configuration parameters are successfully stored

old RMAN configuration parameters:
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF;
new RMAN configuration parameters:
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
new RMAN configuration parameters are successfully stored

sql statement: create pfile=''C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\SERVER\DATAB
ASE\SPFILE2INIT.ORA'' from spfile

Starting backup at 26-JUL-12
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: sid=35 devtype=DISK
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backupset
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backupset
input datafile fno=00001 name=C:\ORACLEXE\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM.DBF
input datafile fno=00003 name=C:\ORACLEXE\ORADATA\XE\SYSAUX.DBF
input datafile fno=00002 name=C:\ORACLEXE\ORADATA\XE\UNDO.DBF
input datafile fno=00004 name=C:\ORACLEXE\ORADATA\XE\USERS.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 26-JUL-12
channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 26-JUL-12
piece handle=C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\XE\BACKUPSET\2012_07_26\
O1_MF_NNNDF_TAG20120726T175506_812M1W98_.BKP tag=TAG20120726T175506 comment=NONE

channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:00:47
Finished backup at 26-JUL-12

Starting Control File and SPFILE Autobackup at 26-JUL-12
piece handle=C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\XE\AUTOBACKUP\2012_07_26
\O1_MF_S_789674071_812M3BF5_.BKP comment=NONE
Finished Control File and SPFILE Autobackup at 26-JUL-12

old RMAN configuration parameters:
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
new RMAN configuration parameters:
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF;
new RMAN configuration parameters are successfully stored

database opened

RMAN retention policy will be applied to the command
RMAN retention policy is set to redundancy 2
using channel ORA_DISK_1
Deleting the following obsolete backups and copies:
Type                 Key    Completion Time    Filename/Handle
-------------------- ------ ------------------ --------------------
Backup Set           1      05-FEB-11
  Backup Piece       1      05-FEB-11          C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\FLASH_RECO
VERY_AREA\XE\BACKUPSET\2011_02_05\O1_MF_NNNDF_TAG20110205T133646_6NT6KHN0_.BKP
Backup Set           2      05-FEB-11
  Backup Piece       2      05-FEB-11          C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\FLASH_RECO
VERY_AREA\XE\AUTOBACKUP\2011_02_05\O1_MF_S_742311382_6NT6LXNJ_.BKP
deleted backup piece
backup piece handle=C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\XE\BACKUPSET\2011
_02_05\O1_MF_NNNDF_TAG20110205T133646_6NT6KHN0_.BKP recid=1 stamp=742311407
deleted backup piece
backup piece handle=C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\XE\AUTOBACKUP\201
1_02_05\O1_MF_S_742311382_6NT6LXNJ_.BKP recid=2 stamp=742311453
Deleted 2 objects
```

In my local system oracle 10g has one user "Manoj" .Please help me how to recover that backup into my local disk.
Thanks in Advance.